# How to make QML flickable content hide outside flickable boundaries?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have a rectangle with a Text and a Flickable in a vertical layout. When I flick the contents of flickable vertically it goes in front of the Text component. How can I make it go behind? How can I make contents of a flickable hide when moving outside its boundaries?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Flickable {
    clip: true

    // ...
}
```